# High School Math: Lines and Angles

Tags: geometry

I have a simple high school math questions about intersecting lines. However, I was unable to answer this question.

[image: click_me_photo]

I thought the answer should be "D" since I really don't see the questions are giving the answer. Please help.

Comment: from the photo it seems they are parallel lines and i don't see any relation between the quantities.

Comment: If the lines are parallel, then the sum of these angles is 180 degrees. Since these lines cross, the sum of these angles is [greater than or less than??] 180 degrees. So $5x > 180$... you should be able to determine that three times a positive number is greater than two times a positive number.

Comment: This doesn't seem much like a linear algebra question...

Comment: I dont see how the line intersecting on the right implies that (5x>180), please help.

Comment: Draw a triangle.

Comment: If the lines were parallel, then any line crossing would have to sum to 180 degrees on both sides of either line, so the interior angles on the same side of the intersecting line must also sum to 180 degrees. Hence, IF the lines were parallel, 2x + 3x = 180. However, the since the lines intersect on the right, they are slightly more open than that on the left of the picture, and hence 2x + 3x > 180.

Answer (score 2):

Since the lines meet to the right,

$$2x+3x>180^{\circ}\implies{}x>36^{\circ}.$$

Hence Quantity $A$>Quantity $B$, which is option A.

Comment: Can you explain, why lines intersecting on the right => 2x+3x>180?

Comment: Its actually a basic rule called an axiom. Precisely it is Axiom 3 (Parallel Axiom) of Euclid's Elements.

Comment: high school math explaination please.

Comment: Um.. Its just a basic rule taken for granted and is one of the things that is "impossible" to be proven.

Comment: @kimberly, if the lines meet, a triangle is formed. The angles in this triangle are $180-2x$, $180-3x$ and a third angle $\alpha\ne0$. Since $180=180-2x+180-3x+\alpha$, we have $5x=180+\alpha > 180$,

Answer (score 0):

In laymen terms, you know that a line must add up to 180degrees. And you also know that the top line is (2x+3x) and the bottom line is (3x+2x) respectively. So 5x must be equal to 180 for a line to exist, and therefore x=36 so the quantities are the same.

Comment: $m$ and $n$ are *not* parallel; they intersect somewhere out to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the points are M and N and the lines meet at P.
MNP form a triangle.
Hence, ang.PMN + PNM + MPN = 180°
Now, PMN =180°-2x°,PNM=180°-3x°
Substituting,
360°+MPN= 180 + 5x°
Or, 5x= 180+MPN
now,MPN>0 Or else m and n coincide,
Hence,5x>180
Or,x>36 .Or,quantity A > quantity B.

Answer (score -1):

That is like two lines: $3x+2x=5x$. There are two angels on the left side. Just look only at them. Do not think about left angels. The angel $3x$ and the angel $2x$ are more than $180$ degrees.